# Geoprocessing tool- output file path location for personal geodatabase in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, personal-geodatabase

I want to know about using a geoprecessing tool:

How do I define an output file path location for a personal geodatabase in an ArcGIS Server geoprocessing folder path?

Comment: Are you trying to write a Geoprocessing Service?  If so, I think you should double-check whether they support personal geodatabases.  I have a feeling that because they can run on Linux, Windows-specific things like Access `*.mdb` files are not supported.

Comment: It's not the fact on Linux sipport so much as the the 32-bit-ness of Access drivers that makes PGDB unsupported in Server. Use file geodatabase instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to write a Geoprocessing Service, I think you should double-check whether they support Personal Geodatabases. I have a feeling that because they can run on Linux, Windows-specific things like Access `*.mdb` files are not supported.

This was clarified in a comment by @Vince:

> It's not the fact on Linux support so much as the 32-bit-ness of
>   Access drivers that makes PGDB unsupported in Server. Use file
>   geodatabase instead.